# Highcharts select chart by button click and adjust width

Tags: html, button, highcharts

I have built multiple charts and want to select one of them by button click. Each button shows the div of one chart and hides the others:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#standd").click(function(){
        $("#Standd").show();
        $("#Verlaufw").hide();
        $("#Verlaufd").hide();
        $("#Standw").hide();
```

});

The divs have a width of 100% by css class.

```
.width {
  min-width: 320px; 
  max-width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

When I change the size of the browser the actual chart adapts the width to the new size. But the others in the background keep their original size. When I click a button and display another chart it has the wrong size. What can I do? See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/9gjf0wxe/28/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `reflow` method to make sure that the chart is fit to its container:

```
$("#standd").click(function() {
  $("#Standd").show();
  $("#Standd").highcharts().reflow();
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vyusa02g/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow